# Может ли VBO быть причиной утечки памяти?

Tags: java, opengl

Может ли данный метод служить причиной утечки памяти (увеличение потребляемой оперативной памяти) в приложении? При том что я вызываю этот метод повторно:

```
public void updateVBO() {

    /** Creating VBO **/

    /** Creating vertex buffer **/

    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(79600 * 18);
    for (int height = 0; height < map.getHeight() - 1; height++) {
        // Calculating Z coord.
        hpoint = -Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI * height / (map.getHeight() - 1);
        hpoint2 = -Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI * (height + 1) / (map.getHeight() - 1);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < map.getWidth(); counter++) {
            // Calculating coord. around Z
            point = ((360.0 / map.getWidth()) * counter) * Math.PI / 180;
            point2 = ((360.0 / map.getWidth()) * (counter + 1)) * Math.PI / 180;

            // Creating circle
            vertex = map.getMap()[counter][height] / 3 + 1;
            vertex4 = map.getMap()[counter][height + 1] / 3 + 1;

            if (counter < map.getWidth() - 1) {
                vertex2 = map.getMap()[counter + 1][height] / 3 + 1;
                vertex3 = map.getMap()[counter + 1][height + 1] / 3 + 1;
            } else {
                vertex2 = map.getMap()[0][height] / 3 + 1;
                vertex3 = map.getMap()[0][height + 1] / 3 + 1;
            }

            // Creating vertex buffer
            vertexBuffer.put((float)(vertex * Math.cos(point) * Math.cos(hpoint))).put((float) Math.sin(hpoint)).put((float)(vertex * Math.sin(point) * Math.cos(hpoint))); // a
            vertexBuffer.put((float)(vertex2 * Math.cos(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint))).put((float)Math.sin(hpoint)).put((float)(vertex2 * Math.sin(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint))); // b
            vertexBuffer.put((float)(vertex4 * Math.cos(point) * Math.cos(hpoint2))).put((float)Math.sin(hpoint2)).put((float)(vertex4 * Math.sin(point) * Math.cos(hpoint2))); // d

            vertexBuffer.put((float)(vertex2 * Math.cos(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint))).put((float)Math.sin(hpoint)).put((float)(vertex2 * Math.sin(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint))); // b
            vertexBuffer.put((float)(vertex3 * Math.cos(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint2))).put((float)Math.sin(hpoint2)).put((float)(vertex3 *Math.sin(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint2))); // c
            vertexBuffer.put((float)(vertex4 * Math.cos(point) * Math.cos(hpoint2))).put((float)Math.sin(hpoint2)).put((float)(vertex4 * Math.sin(point) * Math.cos(hpoint2))); // d

            vertices[counter][height] = new Vector3f((float)(vertex * Math.cos(point) * Math.cos(hpoint)), (float) Math.sin(hpoint), (float)(vertex * Math.sin(point) * Math.cos(hpoint)));
        }
    }
    vertexBuffer.flip();


    /** Creating normal buffer **/
    FloatBuffer normalBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(79600 * 18);
    for (int height = 0; height < map.getHeight() - 2; height++) {

        // Calculating Z coord.
        hpoint = -Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI * height / (map.getHeight() - 1);
        hpoint2 = -Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI * (height + 1) / (map.getHeight() - 1);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < map.getWidth(); counter++) {

            // Calculating coord. around Z
            point = ((360.0 / map.getWidth()) * counter) * Math.PI / 180;
            point2 = ((360.0 / map.getWidth()) * (counter + 1)) * Math.PI / 180;

            // Creating circle
            vertex = map.getMap()[counter][height] / 3 + 1;
            vertex4 = map.getMap()[counter][height + 1] / 3 + 1;

            if (counter < map.getWidth() - 1) {
                vertex2 = map.getMap()[counter + 1][height] / 3 + 1;
                vertex3 = map.getMap()[counter + 1][height + 1] / 3 + 1;
            } else {
                vertex2 = map.getMap()[0][height] / 3 + 1;
                vertex3 = map.getMap()[0][height + 1] / 3 + 1;
            }



            normal1 = Core.getTrangleNormal(
                    new Vector3f((float)(vertex * Math.cos(point) * Math.cos(hpoint)), (float)Math.sin(hpoint), (float)(vertex * Math.sin(point) * Math.cos(hpoint)) ), //a
                    new Vector3f((float)(vertex2 * Math.cos(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint)),(float) Math.sin(hpoint), (float)(vertex2 * Math.sin(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint)) ),
                    new Vector3f((float)(vertex3 * Math.cos(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint2)), (float)Math.sin(hpoint2), (float)(vertex3 *Math.sin(point2) * Math.cos(hpoint2)) )
            );

            normalBuffer.put(-normal1.getX()).put(-normal1.getY()).put(-normal1.getZ()); // a
            normalBuffer.put(-normal1.getX()).put(-normal1.getY()).put(-normal1.getZ()); // b
            normalBuffer.put(-normal1.getX()).put(-normal1.getY()).put(-normal1.getZ()); // d

            normalBuffer.put(-normal1.getX()).put(-normal1.getY()).put(-normal1.getZ()); // b
            normalBuffer.put(-normal1.getX()).put(-normal1.getY()).put(-normal1.getZ()); // c
            normalBuffer.put(-normal1.getX()).put(-normal1.getY()).put(-normal1.getZ()); // d
        }
    }
    normalBuffer.flip();

    vboVertexBuffer = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    vboNormalBuffer = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboNormalBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    normalBuffer = null;
    vertexBuffer = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю да, насколько я вижу вы создаёте при каждом вызове VBO (glGenBuffers()), если вы не уничтожаете этот объект то он остаётся в памяти (видео или оперативной это уже драйвер решит где его хранить в какой-то момент времени). Вы также можете вывести id VBO при каждом вызове, скорее всего они будут разными.

Comment: Т. е. сборщик мусора эту память освободить не сможет? В смысле, когда-нибудь, когда станет собирать все эти объекты?

Comment: Мне кажется сборщик мусора не может освободить эту память, т.к. для уничтожения объекта необходимо вызвать glDeleteBuffers. Я думаю вы можете написать небольшой класс обёртку который в деструкторе будет вызвать glDeleteBuffers. Но не совсем знаком в реализации этих методов в Java, думаю они не должны отличатся от официального API.

Comment: А почему тот деструктор не вызовет его?

Comment: Я не могу быть 100% уверен, т.к. в вопросе даже не указано какое API используется и нет возможности изучить документацию этой библиотеки. Если посмотреть на официальное OpenGL API, то функция glGenBuffers возвращает id, который необходимо уничтожить.

Answer (score -1):

> Может ли данный метод служить причиной утечки памяти

Насколько я знаю, в джаве нет утечек памяти.
Хотя не уверен про циклические ссылки, но в этом методе их нет.

> увеличение потребляемой оперативной памяти

А вот это - запросто. Память будет освобождена, когда сборщику мусора захочется.

---

А вообще, возможно я не прав. Возможно, OpenGL выделяет unmanaged-память...

Comment: Просто после постоянного вызова этого метода (есть ещё один, но в нём не должно быть проблем) количество занятой оперативной памяти доходит до 1 гб.